# Missing pipewire card/sink causing no audio?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, pipewire

I have an AlsaLinux 9 host with a USB audio device.  The sound card device driver loads, aplay shows the device, but when I try to play audio nothing is heard.

I suspect that the problem is a missing sink/card as shown by pactl!

Running as a non-root user:

```
pw-play -v /data/sounds/intruder_alert.wav
sndfile: opened file "/data/sounds/intruder_alert.wav" format 00010002 channels:1 rate:22050
sndfile: using default channel map: MONO
PCM: fmt:s16 rate:22050 channels:1 width:2
rate:22050 latency:2205 (0.100s)
connecting playback stream; target=(null)
stream state changed unconnected -> connecting
stream param change: Spa:Enum:ParamId:Props
stream properties:
        application.name = "pw-play"
        node.name = "pw-play"
        media.type = "Audio"
        media.category = "Playback"
        media.role = "Music"
        media.filename = "/data/sounds/intruder_alert.wav"
        media.name = "/data/sounds/intruder_alert.wav"
        media.format = "WAV (Microsoft)"
        node.rate = "1/22050"
        node.latency = "2205/22050"
        stream.is-live = "true"
        node.autoconnect = "true"
        node.want-driver = "true"
        media.class = "Stream/Output/Audio"
remote 0 is named "pipewire-0"
stream state changed connecting -> paused
stream param change: Spa:Enum:ParamId:Props
stream state changed paused -> error
stream node 35 error: no node available
remote error: id=2 seq:7 res:-2 (No such file or directory): no node available
```

I if issue the command 'pw-cli info 35' (based on "node 35" above) it reports unknown global '35', but I suspect nodes are dynamically created.  The wpctl command shows something interesting:

```
wpctl status
PipeWire 'pipewire-0' [0.3.67, admin@myhost, cookie:1009027964]
 └─ Clients:
        31. wpctl                               [0.3.67, admin@myhost, pid:3833]
        33. WirePlumber                         [0.3.67, admin@myhost, pid:3090]
        34. WirePlumber [export]                [0.3.67, admin@myhost, pid:3090]


Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │
 ├─ Sinks:
 │
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │
 ├─ Sources:
 │
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │
 └─ Streams:


Video
 ├─ Devices:
 │
 ├─ Sinks:
 │
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │
 ├─ Sources:
 │
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │
 └─ Streams:


Settings
 └─ Default Configured Node Names:
```

There appear to be no audio sinks! Should there be?  Do I need to manually add my audio device as a sink?  My audio devices as shown by aplay are:

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: CODEC [USB Audio CODEC], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
sysdefault
    Default Audio Device
oss
    Open Sound System
pipewire
    PipeWire Sound Server
default
    Default ALSA Output (currently PipeWire Media Server)
sysdefault:CARD=CODEC
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
```

How do I add/recreate the missing sinks?  If I try to list the sinks (pactl list sinks) I see only one dummy device, and it's suspended for some reason.

```
Sink #46
        State: SUSPENDED
        Name: auto_null
        Description: Dummy Output
        Driver: PipeWire
        Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
        Channel Map: front-left,front-right
        Owner Module: 4294967295
        Mute: no
        Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        Monitor Source: auto_null.monitor
        Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
        Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY
        Properties:
                node.name = "auto_null"
                device.description = "Dummy Output"
                audio.rate = "48000"
                audio.channels = "2"
                audio.position = "FL,FR"
                media.class = "Audio/Sink"
                factory.name = "support.null-audio-sink"
                node.virtual = "true"
                monitor.channel-volumes = "true"
                factory.id = "18"
                clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
                client.id = "31"
                node.driver = "true"
                factory.mode = "merge"
                audio.adapt.follower = ""
                library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
                object.id = "32"
                object.serial = "46"
        Formats:
                pcm
```

pactl reports NO cards, and NO sinks.  So I tried to add them but failed:

```
 pactl load-module module-alsa-card device=hw:0,0 sink_name=usb_audio sink_properties=device.description=analog
Failure: No such entity

 pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,0 sink_name=usb_audio sink_properties=device.description=analog
Failure: No such entity
```

How do I add this missing card/sink?  (to pipewire or pulseaudio if that's more appropriate)

Comment: To list sinks, you need to issue `pactl list sinks`. This will tell you which sinks you actually have and their statuses.

Comment: I have added that info to the question